# BIRT report cross tabs: How to calculate and display durations of time?

Tags: birt, crosstab

I have a BIRT report that displays some statistics of calls to a certain line on certain days. Now I have to add a new measeure called "call handling time". The data is collected from a MySQL DB:

```
TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(some calculations on the duration of calls in seconds),'%i:%s') AS "CHT"
```

I fail to display the duration in my crosstab in a "mm:ss"-format even when not converting to String. I can display the seconds by not converting them to a time/string but that's not very human readable.
Also I am supposed to add a "grand total" which calculates the average over all days. No problem when using seconds but I have no idea how to do that in a time format.

Which data types/functoins/expressions/settings do I have to use in the query, Data Cube definition and the cross tab cell to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time format is not a duration measure, it cannot be summarized or used for an average. A solution is to keep "seconds" as measure in the datacube to compute aggregations, and create a derived measure for display.

In your datacube, select this "seconds" measure and click "add" to create a derived measure. I would use BIRT math functions to build this expression:

```
  BirtMath.round(measure["seconds"]/60)+":"+BirtMath.mod(measure["seconds"],60)
```

Comment: That did it. I tried something similar before but didn't know I had to use a new derived measure.
Thanks for showing me the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things to watch out for: seconds are displayed as single digit values (if <10). The "seconds" values this is based on is not an integer, so I needed another `round()` for the seconds as well, which resulted in seconds sometimes being "60".
So I had to introduce some more JavaScript conditions to display the correct formatting, including not displaying at all if "0:00".
For the "totals" column I used the summary total of the seconds value and did the exact same thing as below.

This is the actual script I ended up using:

```
if (measure["seconds"] > 0)
{
    var seconds = BirtMath.round(BirtMath.mod(measure["seconds"],60));
    var minutes = BirtMath.round(measure["seconds"]/60);
    if(seconds == 60)
    {
        seconds = 0;
    }
    if (seconds < 10)
    {
        minutes + ":0" + seconds;
    }
    else
    {
        minutes + ":" + seconds;
    }
}
```